# Snmp++ (v3.2) receive informs over TCP

Tags: snmp

I'm trying to implements a simple NMS with snmp++ V3.2 api.
The objective is receive SNMP informs over TCP.

The problem is that I only receive Informs over UDP... I implement an Agent in java with SNMP4J API, but only works when i send via UDP.

I have searched for examples but I only find examples With Agent sending traps/informs via UDP to snmp++ manager....

I also find this: http://lists.agentpp.org/pipermail/agentpp/2005-October/003196.html, it is possible TCP communications is not yet implemented in SNMP++?

The big question is, can snmp++ managers receive alerts via TCP ? If yes, does someone have an example/tutorial to show me ?

Comment: Don't use "TCP/IP" when you actually means TCP, as they are completely different things, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNMP over TCP is defined in [RFC3430](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3430) as an experimental standard. It is not widely adopted, and based on its FAQ SNMP++ does not support it at all,

http://oosnmp.net/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7766018